# How to fix apt-get autoremove?

Tags: apt

The *apt-get autoremove* command does not have any effect in Maverick. How can I solve that?

> *EDIT: Restoring a VM backup containing a clean install solved the
>   problem.*

Comment: What does it means? You can see packages to remove but autoremove doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. There are packages to remove, but the autoremove don't do squat.

Comment: This question would be easier to address if you gave some detail. What packages are tagged for autoremove? Is the package actually installed? `dpkg -l package-name` can cross-check what apt-get lists as not needed. Does removing a specific package yield a different result (e.g. `apt-get remove package-name`)? What does `apt-get check` have to say for itself?

Comment: The packages are installed, because they were installed as dependency of another package, which has been already removed. I have executed autoremove just after removing it and receiving the alert about packages that were not needed anymore. Besides, there were several packages in the Computer Janitor list. I can't run those commands now, because I have already reset the virtual machine, but I still want to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you have a file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove? Autoremove was borked during the Maverick dev cycle, so maybe you ran into some kind of upgrade problem?

Comment: Yes I have it. It wasn't an upgrade. It was a clean install of the final product on a VM.

Comment: does it work if you install aptitude and try the same (corresponding) command?

Comment: Do/did you sometimes use `aptitude` instead of apt-get to install things?

Comment: @lovinglinux Please update your question with the information of things you've tried so it doesn't get buried in the comments.

Comment: @JorgeCastro @msw @htorque @Roland Taylor @JanC Never mind. I can't reproduce the problem after restoring a VM backup with a clean install. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restoring a VM backup containing a clean install solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System > Administration > Computer Janitor. You can find all the packages that can be removed.

---

*But, I am not sure whether it happens in 10.10*

Comment: Thanks. However, I would really like to restore the autoremove functionality, because I don't trust Computer Janitor and also prefer to do it via command-line.

Comment: Me either. But, I am on Ubuntu 10.04. I have no idea regarding that. :|

Comment: I'm also on 10.04 and won't upgrade. The problem is occurring on a VM I use for testing me applications.